# Javascript regex to match only up to 11 digits, one comma, and 2 digits after it

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a textbox where I want only allowed up to 11 digits, an optional comma, and two more digits after it. Anything else should not be rendered when the key is pressed into the textbox:

```
$('#txt').keypress(function (e) {
  var code = e.which;
  var key = String.fromCharCode(code);
  // REGEX TO AVOID CHARS & A DOT (.)
  var pattern = /[a-zA-Z]|\./g;
  var isMatch = pattern.test(key);
  if (isMatch) {
    // DO NOT RENDER CHARS & dot
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

The above code works when an invalid key is pressed, such as a char or a dot, but does not ensure only one comma and only 2 digits afterwards.

This must match:

```
12314
123123,44
```

This must not:

```
12313,6666
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/d2mRk/12/) is a demo.

UPDATE:
Any digit except numbers and comma must be avoided, so the regex I proposed is not valid since only prevents dots (.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should test your complete string, not only the current letter.

```
$('#txt').keypress(function (e) {
    var key = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    var pattern=/^[0-9]{1,11}(,[0-9]{0,2})?$/;

    // test this
    var txt = $(this).val() + key;

    if (!pattern.test(txt)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

​

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/d2mRk/28/)

Comment: Moreover I can put this code on a function and call it on client click. This way I prevent the copy-paste @Koby says further down.

Answer (score 2):

This `regex` will match any string containing 1 up to 11 digits optionally followed by a `,` and exactly 2 more digits: `^[0-9]{1,11}(,[0-9]{2})?$`

Explanation:

```
^             # Match the start of the string
[0-9]{1,11}   # Followed by a maximum of 11 digits
(,[0-9]{2})?  # Optionally followed by a comma and 2 more digits 
$             # Followed by the end of the string
```

See it in action [here](http://rubular.com/r/60xWl27BrC).

Comment: The comma is not matched and I'm able to enter more than 11 digits.
http://jsfiddle.net/d2mRk/14/

Comment: please not I want a javascript regex, not a ruby one.

Comment: The `regex` matches your criteria, not a `javascript` guy so not sure what is wrong in this context. Ruby isn't relevant it's just the demo site this is only `ERE`.

Comment: @senyortoni It actually is matched, but a regex that matches a string as it's being built, and a regex that matches the final string are two different things.  It will match `11,22` but not `11,` thus the `,` is blocked.

Comment: This regex is the same in javascript and ruby. @senyortoni - You are suggesting the `123,` is a valid input, because you do validation while typing. By the way: validation while typing that block keys is a very poor choice - the user can still paste text, drag it, delete parts of it, etc. Also - your code is very wrong, you use the pattern on a key - a single character at each step - not the whole text.

Comment: @sudo_o - You probably want the `$` out of the parentheses: `^[0-9]{1,11}(,[0-9]{0,2})?$`

Comment: You may be right @kobi I should allow type anything and check de regex in the onlick event or what do you propose?

Comment: @senyortoni - I'd strongly recommend the jquery validation plugin.

Comment: @Kobi those two regex are functionally equivalent.  (Though I do think that your version is clearer, and the one used 99.9% of the time.)

Comment: @Corbin - Not really. `^a(b|$)` would validate `"ab!@#$%^"` - the end is not anchored.

Comment: @Kobi Whoops.  Not the same thing at all...  Seems that it's about sleep time for me >.<.