# How to allow only 2 digits and 1 digit after the comma (.)?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the problem that I can't get the proper `RegExp` together.
My Goal is to allow up to 3 digits before the comma, and ONLY IF there is a decimal, then 1 digit after the comma. Which `RegExp` or Regexes do I have to use for this behavior?

Wanted allowed outcomes: 000.0, 00.0, 0.0, 000, 00, 0

thats the current code, but the problem is that here also 4 digits can be placed without a decimal:

```
inputFormatters: [
  FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'^\d{1,3}\.?\d{0,1}')),
],
```

I already scrolled through these but they are not working for me:

[Javascript Regex to allow only 2 digit numbers and 3 digit numbers as comma separated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53813697/javascript-regex-to-allow-only-2-digit-numbers-and-3-digit-numbers-as-comma-sepa)

[Javascript regex to match only up to 11 digits, one comma, and 2 digits after it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13491589/javascript-regex-to-match-only-up-to-11-digits-one-comma-and-2-digits-after-it)

[Jquery allow only float 2 digit before and after dot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30965201/jquery-allow-only-float-2-digit-before-and-after-dot)

[Flutter - Regex in TextFormField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56390839/flutter-regex-in-textformfield)

[Allow only two decimal number in flutter input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54454983/allow-only-two-decimal-number-in-flutter-input/64947831#64947831)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a regex expert, so I can only suggest you using this helper function:

```
  bool match(String input) {
    if (input.split('.').length == 1) {
      // if there is no dot in the string
      // returns true if the length is < 4
      return (input.length < 4) ? true : false;
    } else if (input.split('.').length > 1){
      // if there is more than one dot in the string
      return false;
    } else {
      // if there is a dot in the string
      // returns true if there are < 4 digits before the dot and exactly 1 digit 
      // after the dot
      return (input.split('.')[0].length < 4 && input.split('.')[1].length == 1)
          ? true
          : false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: how to use this in a custom class extending 'TextInputFormatter' or as a inputFormatter?

Comment: Like BambinoUA did it in his answer, with a validator. PS I edited the code a bit.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using your solution ripped off with my first 'FilteringTextInputFormatter' together.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I helped you. If you have any more questions regarding this ask me.

Answer (score 2):

```
RegExp(r'^\d{0,3}(\.\d{1})?$')
```

try this regex

also I think by comma your mean decimal (.) and considering you want 3 digits before decimal and 1 decimal after decimal

```
TextFormField(
  autoValidateMode: AutoValidateMode.always,
  validator: (value) {
    return RegExp(r'^\d{0,3}(\.\d{1})?$').hasMatch(value) ? null : 'Invalid value';
  },
)
```

Comment: unfortunately does not work in dart, and yes I meant a decimal, I edited my question

Comment: yes you have to use validator, let me edit the answer

Comment: @Nuqo I have added the example that how you can use RegEx in dart have a look

Comment: also you may mark this as accepted if it worked for you

Answer (score 1):

Input formatter is not the case here because it *formats* data visually and your desired formats includes each other. You should use `TextFormField` and `validator` property with @Andrej's validator or use `RegExp`.

```dart
TextFormField(
  autoValidateMode: AutoValidateMode.always,
  validator: (value) {
    return RegEx(r'^\d{1,3}(\.\d)?$').hasMatch(value) ? null : 'Invalid value';
  },
)
```

RegExp is working [here](https://dartpad.dev/489f20b63f16b9c714e586a517a43384).