# Want only one or|two digits number before the decimal point in textfield flutter. And User can't add more than three digits after the decimal point

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

Only one or two digits number before the decimal point in texfFormField flutter. And User can't add more than three digits after the decimal point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use RegExp class

```
final isValidNumber = RegExp(r'^([0-9]{2})*\.[0-9]{2}$');

if (!isValidNumber .hasMatch(number))
    numbererror = "Please Enter Valid Name";
else
   numbererror = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

If your String what the user typed is called `value`:

```
List<String> split = value.split('.');
if (split.elementAt(0).length > 2 || split.elementAt(1).length > 3) print('Not valid');
```

If you need something more advanced: [How to allow only 2 digits and 1 digit after the comma (.)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64948159/how-to-allow-only-2-digits-and-1-digit-after-the-comma?noredirect=1&lq=1)